# Triggering on a ScrollViewer's scroll bar visibility (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, scrollviewer

Is it possible to create a Trigger that is triggered based on a `ScrollViewer`'s scroll bar visibility? I have a `ScrollViewer` with its `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` set to `Auto` and I want to change some of the `ScrollViewer`'s properties only when the scroll bar is actually visible.

Something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ScrollViewer.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsScrollBarVisible" Value="True">
            <!-- Setters -->
        </Trigger>
    </ScrollViewer.Triggers>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Trigger on [`ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.computedverticalscrollbarvisibility.aspx).