# How to put ellipsis (...) in RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, ellipsis

I want to put an ellipsis (..) in the rich text box.

In normal `TextBlock`, `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"` has a property that limits the length to allow ellipsis representation, but rich text boxes do not. And it should only be implemented as a rich textbox now. Text blocks are not allowed.

I'd like to trim by two or three lines and add an ellipsis (..) option. Is there any good way?

I want to show you how I'm using RichTextBox, but the reputation is low.

Comment: While TextBlock is designed to *show* text, any TextBox is designed to *edit* text. Editing text which is not presented in full doesn't really work out to well so it seems like you want to *show* text but for some reason you prefer to do so in a RichTextBox... care to explain some background to this decision?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextBox TextTrimming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227014/textbox-texttrimming)

Comment: @grek40 You are correct, that i can do it with TextBlock. But I am using a RichTextBox which can support the formatted text which may contain text like.

So for doing this we used rtf text format which is saved in database and it preserves all the formatting, I don't know whether Textbloxk supports the text formatting very easily or not.

Now already RichTextBox is used and it will be very difficult to replace it with TextBlock, so please suggest any way to do it with RichTextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't**

The ellipsis concept is, as stated by grek40, something that only works when *displaying* text.
As an example, say the ellipsis is displayed, and the user tries to partially select some text in your `RichTextBox`, including the ellipsis, what would the selected result be? You can't tell.

**Maybe**

Since an ellipsis is usually a replacement for a `Scrollbar`, hiding text instead of allowing you to access it by scrolling, you might be able to fake it by using a WPF Style.
Create a Style that displays an icon/picture of an ellipsis (placement is up to you) whenever the [Scrollbar visibility trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580036/triggering-on-a-scrollviewers-scroll-bar-visibility-wpf) is triggered. You would need to disable the `Scrollbar` once the ellipsis is visible.
This obviously requires more effort than simply setting a property, and it can easily become a User Experience nightmare if not carefully implemented, so be warned.

Note: Another comment (by Walt Ritscher) linked to a similar question, the solution there is similar to this one.

**Alternative Maybe**

Another faked ellipsis could be achieved by using two different `RichTextBox` controls.
The first `RichTextBox` would have set `ReadOnly` to `true`. Trim your text to a maximum allowed length, and append an ellipsis and display it inside this first `RichTextBox`.
When the user need to edit the text hide the first `RichTextBox` and display a second `RichTextBox` that contains your entire text.

Comment: Please review my comments above.

Comment: @KangDongGyun, you didn't add any new details about your question. Neither `RichTextBox` nor `TextBox` (which is NOT `TextBlock`) support ellipsis. Using `TextBlock` isn't possible because that doesn't support the special text formatting of a RichTextBox, which you need. You can only achieve this with a hack of some sort, as I already stated.

Comment: @KangDongGyun I added another alternative, it should be much easier to implement. Still just a hack though.

Comment: I already know that it is difficult to implement normally. Thank you for your good feedback. I am very pleased with your kind explanation.